How to ensure consistent axis scaling when plots in a panel have different axis sizes?
The following code makes a panel with eight plots in a specific layout. It does everything I want except that axis scales are not consistent across all plots. I need the distance between zero and one on the X axis to be the same in all plots. I have failed to find a solution to this. Any suggestions are welcome (not necessarily using only the packages I'm using below).
You can increase size in some plots if necessary to make this possible. For example, if it's necessary to increase the X axis limits of p3 to from 0-6 to 0-7 to arrange the smaller plots in a way that axes match, that's ok. But you can't reduce the limits, nor make all plots have the same limits.
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Define plots
p1 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  ggtitle("p1")

p2 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  ggtitle("p2")

p3 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  ggtitle("p3")

p4 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  ggtitle("p4")

p5 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  ggtitle("p5")

p6 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  ggtitle("p6")

p7 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  ggtitle("p7")

p8 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  ggtitle("p8")

# Set desired design
design <- "AAABBB
           CCCCCC
           DDDEEE
           FFGGHH"

# Plot panel with specific design
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 +
  plot_layout(design = design)


I am sure there may be many different ways to solve this issue, but one idea that came to my mind is fixing the coordinate ratio using coord_fixed and fixing the height of the plots.
The documentation states

A fixed scale coordinate system forces a specified ratio between the physical representation of data units on the axes. The ratio represents the number of units on the y-axis equivalent to one unit on the x-axis.

Because everyone of your graphs has the same y limit (6) and we will set the height of every graph the same, the physical representation of one unit on the x-axis will remain the same regardless of the limits imposed.
See the following example:
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Define plots
p1 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p1")

p2 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p2")

p3 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p3")

p4 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p4")

p5 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p5")

p6 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p6")

p7 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p7")

p8 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p8")

# Set desired design
design <- "AAABBB
           CCCCCC
           DDDEEE
           FFGGHH"

# Plot panel with specific design
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7 + p8 +
  plot_layout(design = design, heights = 100)

)
Created on 2024-06-23 with reprex v2.1.0
It's not super pretty, but I hope it helps!
Edit:
Here's another example using cowplot
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> Warning: package 'cowplot' was built under R version 4.4.1

# Define plots
p1 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p1")

p2 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p2")

p3 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p3")

p4 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p4")

p5 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p5")

p6 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p6")

p7 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p7")

p8 <- ggplot() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 0.125) +
  ggtitle("p8")


# Plot panel with specific design
grid <- plot_grid(
  plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 1),
  plot_grid(p3, nrow = 1),
  plot_grid(p4, p5, nrow = 1),
  plot_grid(p6, p7, p8, nrow = 1),
  ncol = 1
)

ggsave2("grid.pdf")
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
# just for show
magick::image_convert(magick::image_read_pdf("grid.pdf"), "grid.png")
#> PDF error: No display font for 'Symbol'
#> PDF error: No display font for 'ArialUnicode'

)
Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

It seems to have worked in the figure you attached, but the code you provided isn't generating the same output here.

Would you be able to provide a reproducible example of what output you are getting? Note that if you have changed your y limits so they are not all the same number of units long, you will need to adjust for that

It seems to work when seeing the output within R Studio, but for some reason, when exporting the figure as a pdf, the units on the x-axis don't remain the same across plots.

Try using ggsave or cowplot::ggsave2. See the cowplot example

I'm just copying, pasting, and running your example using cowplot, and still the units on the x-axis aren't the same across plots. One x-axis unit in p3 is slightly larger than in p1 in the pdf saved with ggsave2("grid.pdf"). And in the bottom plots it's even larger.
